# React render string as html from server response

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have problem. Server generate html code and returns to me, with script tags, i needed render this into my React component. I must render the html code (like dangerouslySetInnerHTML), and run script tags. You do not know the solution? Sorry for my english.

Comment: Perhaps shading some light on what is it that you're trying to achieve would help, on a deeper level. What does the html contain besides the script tags? Why does the server *have* to send the html? How and how frequently is this going to be done on a single page? What have you tried and what didn't work? SO isn't the place for vague questions. Be specific so that it's easier for others to help you.

Comment: @GoshaArinich sorry, i tried dangerouslySetInnerHTML, and `html()` from jquery. Server send the html because this element can generate only on the server. Let's say there is a dynamic list, and each element of the list must be requested html by ID.

Answer (score 2):

You can render the script tags from `componentWillMount` or `componentDidMount`, but not `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` for security purposes. You could easily strip out `<script>` tags with regular expressions and run that from one of the said methods.